# Problema para criar procedure com variável MySQL

Tags: mysql, variáveis, procedure

Estou com um problema para criar uma procedure no MySQL.

A procedure é a seguinte.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE trata_busca()
BEGIN
   DECLARE excessao INT default 0; <--- LINHA QUE ESTA APONTANDO PROBLEMA
   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET excessao = 1; 
   ... 
   {500 linhas de código aqui}
   ...
END
```

A mensagem de erro é a seguinte:

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''
```

Aqui esta a versão do  MySQL no servidor

```
"innodb_version"    "5.5.39"
"protocol_version"  "10"
"slave_type_conversions"    ""
"version"   "5.5.39"
"version_comment"   "MySQL Community Server (GPL)"
"version_compile_machine"   "x86"
"version_compile_os"    "Win32"
```

Preciso criar essa variável excessao para usar transaction. Estou usando uma código que eu vi no DevMedia para poder adicionar Transaction em um proc que esta funcional e rodando em produção.
Porém ao tentar adicionar a linha de declaração da variável não esta funcionando.

Alguma solução para isso?

Comment: Tente declarar d aseguinte forma: `DECLARE excessao INT unsigned DEFAULT 0;`

Comment: Tentei, continua dando erro.